# Test for convergence of $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x\log (1+x)}}dx$

Tags: calculus

Test for convergence of $\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x\log (1+x)}}dx$.

I tried substituting $y=\log(1+x)$ to get $x=e^y-1$ so that

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\exp{(1+y-e^y)}}{\sqrt{y(e^y-1)}}dy$$

and then using L'Hopital's rule to show that the limit of the integrand goes to infinity but it's not working. I also tried bounding below by some function such as $e^{-x}/\sqrt{x}$ but that converged so it's not very useful.

Comment: You may want to formalize the following: $\log(1+x)\simeq x$ for small $x$. $e^{-x}$ is roughly $1$ for small $x$. This makes the integrand $\frac{1}{x}$ for small $x$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $$\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x\log (1+x)}} \sim \frac1x, \quad x \to +0.$$